# Exactly what does the Wilcoxon signed rank test compare?

Tags: terminology, wilcoxon-signed-rank

The Wilcoxon signed rank test is a nonparametric version of the t-test. That is, it converts parametric values, which may be non-normally distributed into **EDIT for Glen_B** more normally distributed signed ranks; e.g., from Harrell and Slaughter "Biostatistics for Biomedical Research" ([BBR](https://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf)) 7.2 *We look up |z| against the normal distribution*. A complication arises when ties occur. Now the problem is, that when the test is usually described it is presented as a "test of median values," which is no more true than it is a test of mean values, as the mean and median are the same for a normal distribution arrived at by nonparametric transformation. This is complicated by the fact that there is an actual [median test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/meditest.htm), which is a Chi-squared test for different median values, and which is certainly not the same thing as signed rank test which combines the rankings of paired samples of the data.

So the **question** is, "Rather than say that the Wilcoxon test is a test for "median values" which if true applies to the nonparametric transformed random variates, what words would best describe what the Wilcoxon test actually is?"

A further complication is that in the ranked data, the transformed medians correspond position-wise to the data medians (if odd), but the values being compared are different, i.e., ranks, and not data medians.

**Edit** In the one-sample case, we would be asking how plausibly the signed ranks sums would include a given point value, but there is no comparison single value for the signed rank sums, but rather a region or range in which the same probability would apply to slightly different tested points, thus statements suggesting that the signed rank sum test is a test of median or mean values do not make sense. Think about the sign test for a moment, the same probability occurs irrespective of what the mean or median is, as long as the relative number of sample values greater or less than a comparison value is maintained. The Wilcoxon test is similar to the sign test but with the additional information of signed rank sums providing better power.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140178/discussion-on-question-by-carl-exactly-what-does-the-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-c).

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few useful ways to think of the signed ranks test.  The following notes may not be technically rigorous.

- One way to think of the hypothesis tested is described by Frank Harrell in a comment here: "As stated earlier it tests precisely whether the probability that a randomly chosen pair of values sums to a positive number is equal to 0.5 or not." [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569439/how-to-interprete-‌​and-describe-the-res‌​ults-of-a-wilcoxon-s‌​igned-rank-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569439/how-to-interprete-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Band-describe-the-res%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bults-of-a-wilcoxon-s%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bigned-rank-test). @statmerkur mentioned in the chat the Wikipedia description of the hypotheses ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Null_and_alternative_hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Null_and_alternative_hypotheses).
- With the understanding that it first takes the differences of the paired values, and then uses the ranks, the test looks to see if the [signed rank values of the differences] values are symmetrically distributed around zero.  That is, there are two ways you could get an e.g. significant result. a) If the values are symmetrical around a value other than zero, or b) If the values are not symmetric even if centered (in some sense) around zero.
- It could be considered a test of location of the differences, where location is understood through the lens of signed ranks.  This "location" may be related to the Hodges–Lehmann estimator. ( I don't understand this relationship well enough to say anything more definitive.)

As a parenthetical comment, personally, I think it's not helpful to describe tests like Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney or Wilcoxon signed rank tests as tests of median, even if we add caveats about assumptions of the distributions of data or populations for this interpretation.  As far as I can tell, this avenue just causes confusion in people trying to understand these tests.  We have different methods to test medians if that's what we really want.

Comment: Yeah, OK, but, what the test does is calculate the W-statistic, the lesser magnitude of w- and w+ for the two-tailed test, and with interpolation of summed ranks for ties and some type of counting of possible outcomes to calculate a probability. I've seen Wilcoxon called a "pseudo-median" test or alternatively a "mean" test which makes no sense. It is a probability test based on the W-statistic as a measure of location, and is (opaquely) touted as related to [Walsh averages and the Hodges-Lehmann estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215953/99274), which is a so-what?

Comment: +1 If you can please give me more about W and *p*, perhaps something about whether or not normality is at all relevant in this context, and why it is preferred to t-testing when that fails quality assurance for non-normality.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that we ***should*** be teaching that the signed rank test is the go-to test if a [paired, or one-sample] *t*-test isn't appropriate.  That may have been a reasonable approach before we had easy access to re-sampling approaches.  But also, I think it's important to emphasize to students that different tests address different hypotheses.  ...

Comment: ... With the signed rank test, to me, thinking of the paired case, say from *Time 1* to *Time 2*, it asks if the values tended to go up more than they tended to go down, with the "more" also capturing a sense of magnitude.  To me, this is a reasonable way to assess things in certain cases, and may be a better approach than comparing means in some cases.

Comment: How would you feel about calling it a rank weighted sign test?